# Connection String setting for non-relational database (legacy) in Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-config, web.config-transform

I am working on a new asp.net web application which has to connect and use an old legacy database. It is not an RDBMS as SQL Server but instead a C-Treive so I should be using **ODBC** or in my C#/ASP code.  I will be using this namespace:

**System.Data.Odbc;**

Now, my problem is in Web.Config file. I have not used ODBC for years and every time I run the application it throws an error indicating it is an invalid connection.

`
 
 add name="DB_Connection" connectionString="Driver=ODBCDriver;server=172.xxx.xxx.xxx;" providerName="System.Data.Odbc"/>

```
    internal OdbcConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        return conn;
    }
```

`

> {"ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not
>   found and no default driver specified"}

This is what I have declared in the **Web.Config**:

Honestly, I am not sure what would be considered Catalog in this case since it is not SQL Server.

I will appreciate your inputs.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: What is `ConnectionString`.  Need that.

Comment: This is what I have used and didn't help in web.config file under   <connectionStrings> tag:    `add name="DB_Connection" connectionString="Driver=ODBCDriver;server=172.xxx.xxx.xxx;" providerName="System.Data.Odbc"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to use a DSN (Data Source Name), it's just that traditionally ODBC used them. A DSN is really just a connection-string that is stored systemwide and referenced by name. Just find the actual, underlying connection-string and then save that in your `<connectionStrings>` element.

Note that the full ODBC connection string will specify the driver name.

Comment: Dai, thank you for your input but what should I do about the elements that have to be filled in it? e.g. server name, database name? currently, I am using `<add name="DB_Connection" connectionString="Driver=ODBCDriver;server=172.xxx.xxx.xxx;" providerName="System.Data.Odbc"/>` would it be possible to show me an example?  I will appreciate it greatly!

Comment: The driver I need to use for the connection is called BBj ODBC Driver so then I changed it to  `    <add
      name="DB_Connection"
      connectionString="Driver={BBj ODBC Driver};server=172.xxx.xxx.xxx;"
      providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />`  However, when I trace it I can see the database name, driver and DataSource have no value.

Comment: @amitkohan I can't really help you with specifics. I believe the product you're using is now called "C-treeRTG" and is maintained by FairCom: https://www.faircom.com/products/c-treertg - I suggest you contact them for specific advice with your database system.

Comment: sure will do that but by any chance do you know how the format will be?   Thank you again!

Comment: @amitkohan I don't, sorry.

Comment: Solution: I changed my code in DBContext.cs (handles database/tables methods)  from: `private static string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB_Connection"].ConnectionString;`
To: `private static string ConnectionString = "DSN=TheDsnName";`                                            I need to remind that  `TheDsnName` is defined in Data Source (ODBC) under Administrative Tool in Windows Control Panel. Also, `DB_Connection` is the tag defined in `web.config` I consider this as temporary solution but have to find a way to do this in `web.config`

Comment: @amitkohan You could always just store the value `Dsn=TheDsnName` in your app.config file and still read it using the ConnectionString API.

Comment: if it is doable to do so in web.config then it would be great! may I ask how you define it? because currently I am saving it in my dbContext.cs file which is not good.